# PHP: YouTube v3 API... Retrieve last 50 videos from Watch Later list and add them to a playlist

Tags: php, youtube-api

```
<?php

  require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
  require_once 'Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey('{YOUR-API-KEY}');
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  $nextPageToken = '';
  $htmlBody = '<ul>';

  do {
    $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
    'playlistId' => '{PLAYLIST-ID-HERE}',
    'maxResults' => 50,
    'pageToken' => $nextPageToken));

    foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'], $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
    }

    $nextPageToken = $playlistItemsResponse['nextPageToken'];
  } while ($nextPageToken <> '');

  $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video list</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= $htmlBody ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How to do it for the `Watch Later Playlist`? Already have the API key.
Then, for any `videoId -> insert the video in another playlist...`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key‌​={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you can get the `playlistId` of your watch later list (under `watchLater`). You need to authenticate to get the results. If this is a one off thing then use the API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list.

Once you have the `playlistId` then you can use the code in your question to get the videos (and videoIDs) from the list. You will need to add OAuth authentication code before making the call examples here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

To upload a video into a new playlist there is a PHP sample in the API docs here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads

Comment: thank you, I don't have to "upload" a video... I have to insert all those videos into a playlist.. the videos are already there

Comment: then, even if did login on youtube and dev console both and already created server and browser api key https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key‌​={YOUR_API_KEY} from browser returns error as unauthenticated. Why? thanks

Comment: Try it from the API explorer and switch OAuth on.

Comment: ok, sorry...understood, that is done with OAuth 2.0 here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: the part which is not clear to me is how to insert "for any videoId" the related videos in the target playlist...

Comment: and also: put the case that some videos are already present in the destination playlist, are they just ignored?

Comment: the fact is that YouTube before was easier... 'cause you could add all the selected videos eg. in the favourite playlist without using API... it's not good if they force users to use API for that...now you can just do it one by one! incredible....

Comment: ohhhh found, they tried to hide the function! lol :-D if you go on Watch Later playlist there is a "3 vertical points" button on the right...if you click you can "Add all to..." they are xxxxxx! sorry... I don't need it anymore and thank you very much! -)